# MySQL Error 1251 on 5.7.33 - Can't log in

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, errors, logins

```
ERROR 1251 (08004): Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

I have recently imported a backup into a test environment so I can review some slow queries, and just ran into this issue when trying to log in via command line. I had only made a change to `@@sql_mode` due to the query having an issue with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. After a restart to make sure the change took effect, I get the above error message and can't log in. I tried changing my my.cnf file to include `skip-grant-tables`, but this hasn't worked. Am I out of luck, or are there any other ways I can get myself back in?

Comment: [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html), [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  ALTER USER Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html) (see *auth_option* description) and [default_authentication_plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin).

Comment: Thanks @Akina. The How-To Reset portion helped (which I thought I had attempted, but maybe not...) to get me back in. It looks like the backup had overwritten my configuration for the root user, so I made the adjustments when I got back in and all is good now!